# Which version OroCRM support to Magento 2.3.4?

Tags: integration, crm, magento-2.3, orocrm

I am using Magento 2.3.4, which version OroCRM support.
Best tutorials to integrate Magento 2.3 and OroCRM?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, OroCRM is not integrated with Magento 2.

Comment: I don't know about any plans for integration. If anything would be changed, the company will mention it in the blog (https://oroinc.com/orocrm/blog/) or release notes (https://github.com/oroinc/crm-application/releases)